# Hiding a part of layout by clicking a button in pyqt

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I have a GUI which looks like the one in the picture:
[image]

It was designed in Qt designer now what i want is to make the layout like the one in the picture below by clicking the customize button basically hiding/showing a part of layout.

[image]

Now when i hit close button it needs to revert back to the initial state. How can i do this in the qt designer(if possible)
If not possible can anyone tell me how to do it Pyqt.
Will the command link button(qt designer) work for this function to happen??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could connect signals and slots:

- connect customizeButton, clicked() to customizeLayout, show()
- connect customizeButton, clicked() to customizeButton, hide()
- connect closeButton, clicked() to customizeLayout, hide()
- connect closeButton, clicked() to customizeButton, show()

I guess you get the idea?

You will most likely have to provide some default settings in your program to initially hide the customizeLayout, as I fear you cannot hide stuff by default from the Designer (but I'm not sure about this - just see if there's a "visible" attribute).